# NestJS Error while importing a module while trying to implement JWT

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am learning Nest and I want to implement JWT along with mongoose. I was following the guide on nestjs website but i keep getting the error:

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the UsersService (?). Please make sure that the argument User at index [0] is available in the UsersModule context.
```

Here is my code.

app.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      envFilePath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../.env'),
    }),
    MongooseModule.forRoot(process.env.MONGODB_URI),
    AuthModule,
    UsersModule,
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer.apply(JwtMiddleware).forRoutes('*');
  }
}
```

auth.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UsersModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '30d' },
    }),
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  providers: [AuthService],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

users.module.ts

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([{ name: User.name, schema: UserSchema }]),
  ],
  providers: [UsersService],
  exports: [UsersService],
})
export class UsersModule {}
```

UPDATE

user.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class UsersService {
  constructor(
    @Inject(User.name)
    private userModel: Model<IUser>,
  ) {}

  async findOne(email: string): Promise<IUser | undefined> {
    const user = this.userModel.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });

    return user;
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your `UsersService` look like?

Comment: i also updated user.module.ts, same error. werid

Comment: Hello, to be honest I'm not a NestJs master , but I see through the official NestJs exemple, `findOne(..)` should be called with `.exec()` method, you can check [this link](https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/d92a64e7e23a10920ef7d6b5e0916359463fdd3b/sample/06-mongoose/src/cats/cats.service.ts#L21)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@Inject(User.name)` to `@InjectModel(User.name)` [like the docs show](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/mongodb#model-injection)